# Evitar cambio de tabpanel al hacer postback asp.net vb

Tags: nav, updatepanel

Solicito de su conocimiento, soy programador novato; mi planteamiento es el siguiente:
Uso nav-tabs con el CSS bootstrap, para mostrar un formulario y un listado con filtro, en este segun panel de filtrado de información, cuando se lanza el postback el panel cambia al que esta definido como activo.

He buscado por la web algunas soluciones que no he sabido aplicar correctamente por lo que no me son funcionales, les comparto el codigo:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="text-TituloPanel"> CONCEPTOS DE EGRESOS</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#secConcepto" aria-controls="" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Concepto de Egresos</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#secListadoConcepto" aria-controls="" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Listado de Conceptos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="secConcepto">

                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="secListadoConcepto">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var currentTabIndex = "0";

                        $tab = $("#tabs").tabs({
                            activate: function (e, ui) {
                                currentTabIndex = ui.newTab.index().toString();
                                sessionStorage.setItem('tab-index', currentTabIndex);
                            }
                        });

                        if (sessionStorage.getItem('tab-index') != null) {
                            currentTabIndex = sessionStorage.getItem('tab-index');
                            console.log(currentTabIndex);
                            $tab.tabs('option', 'active', currentTabIndex);
                        }
                        $('#btn-sub').on('click', function () {
                            sessionStorage.setItem("tab-index", currentTabIndex);
                            //window.location = "/Home/Index/";
                        });
                    });
            </script>

            <div class="panel-footer panel-default">
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

He quitado código pero en esencia es el esqueleto del webform, utilizamos Masterpages.

Les reitero he aplicado aquí en este código fragmentos de algunos ejemplos donde han funcionado para otros usuarios, pero no para mí, tengo el scripmanager en la masterpage.

De antemano agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución utilizando Tab Container Extender, les dejo el enlace espero a alguien le sea de utilidad, les comparto el enlace: **Shaili Dashora** [Ajax Tab Container Extender in ASP.Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/955025/ajax-tab-container-extender/)

Hasta luego.